# Creating json for special values in the dict of dicts python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have dictionary like that:

```
dic={'61': {'NAME': 'John', 'LASTNAME': 'X', 'EMAIL': 'X@example.com', 'GRADE': '99'}, '52': {'NAME': 'Jennifer', 'LASTNAME': 'Y', 'EMAIL': 'Y@example.com', 'GRADE': '98'}}
obj = json.dumps(dic,indent=3)
print(obj)
```

I want to create Json for some values.

```
{
          "NAME": "John",
          "LASTNAME": "X",
          
     ,
          "NAME": "Jennifer",
          "LASTNAME": "Y"
}
```

Any idea for help?

Comment: The provided output is invalid, you cannot have duplicated keys, please double-check

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to keep the values of your original data without the indices and also filter out some of them (keep only "NAME" and "LASTNAME"). You can do so by using a combination of dictionary and list comprehensions:

```
array = [{k:v for k,v in d.items()if k in ("NAME","LASTNAME")} for d in dic.values()]
```

This creates the following output:

```
>>> array
[{'NAME': 'John', 'LASTNAME': 'X'}, {'NAME': 'Jennifer', 'LASTNAME': 'Y'}]
```

Comment: Thanks it is very useful! I have a array for printing values how can i add to this loop? Example: I have a printing_values=["NAME","LASTNAME"]

Comment: You can replace the tuple `("NAME", "LASTNAME")` in my code with `printing_values`.